# Unix one-liner to extract substring from all files in a directory and subdirectories

Tags: unix

I'm looking for a UNIX one-liner that will output to a file all occurrences of NSLocalizedString (from that word to the end of the line) in all files in the current directory and all subdirectories. I've googled, but haven't found a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -type f -exec fgrep NSLocalizedString {} \+ | \
    sed -e 's/^.*\(NSLocalizedString.*\)$/\1/' > ../your_output_file
```

Comment: You could potentially use grep -ri 'NSLocalizedString' | sed right?

Comment: This gets the substring from files in the CWD, but not the subdirectories. Mark, using your suggestion leads to a "grep: warning: recursive search of stdin" error

Comment: I'm sorry, I was intending to provide a high level command. grep -ri 'NSLocalizedString' * | sed <rest of command>.  You could potentially use ack-grep for this as well, but that's not usually installed by default.

Comment: @user1161418 - By `This gets the substring from files in the CWD, but not the subdirectories` do you mean Mark's suggestion or my answer? I assure you, `find .` *starts* in the current directory but descends through subdirectories. (I tested this one-liner before posting it)

Comment: Good solution: Though I will suggest to use ':' in sed substitute command instead of / to make it visually less harmful

Answer (score 0):

`find <directory> -type f -print | xargs grep NSLocalizedString | tee <outputfile>` should do what you're looking for, if I understand the question right...

Comment: You want to do `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...` to handle files/directories with spaces in the names.

Comment: add `-n 100` or something after `xargs` to limit the number of files it will process in one batch